# Chrome Extensiom submit button inside anchor tag does not redirect

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, submit-button, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm building a simple chrome extension. In it, I'm trying to make the submit button in a form redirect the user to a different page after submitting the form but I can't get it to work. I have tried the following:

```
//First way
const button = document.querySelector('.button');
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.location.href = 'results.html';
});

//Second way
const form = document.querySelector('form');
form.onsubmit = redirect;

function redirect() {
    location.href = 'results.html';
    console.log("successfully redirected");
};

//Third way
<button onclick="window.location.href='results.html'" class="button" type="submit">Submit</button>

//Fourth way
<a href="results.html">
    <button class="button" type="submit">Submit</button>
</a>
```

My form looks like this

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:3000/sleep">
    <label> How much did you sleep last night?
      <input name="duration" type="number">
    </label>
    <label> How well did you sleep?
      <div>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="quality" value="bad">
          Bad
        </label>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="quality" value="ok">
          Ok
        </label>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="quality" value="good">
          Good
        </label>
      </div>
    </label>
    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="1">
    <button class="button" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I tried redirecting to a page using different elements other than the submit button and that somehow worked. Is there something about the submit button that doesn't allow me to redirect? I am trying to make the user experience a little better by redirecting as soon as the form submits so I would like to redirect using the submit button if that's possible. Also, I don't know if this is relevant but I am using manifest v3.

Answer (score 0):

Use in this way

```js
function clickHandler(e) {
    chrome.tabs.update({url: "https://stackoverflow.com"});
    window.close(); // Note: window.close(), not this.close()
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
});
```

Comment: It didn't work for me :( I am pretty sure my problem has to do with this being a chrome extension. I am pretty new to working with chrome extensions and so there's a lot of things I still don't understand.

Comment: Sorry I don't think I was too clear in my question. My chrome extension when opened makes a little window with which you can interact with my extension. I am not trying to redirect the user to a different page using tabs, I am trying to redirect the **popup window** to a different page. Your method works fine for redirecting **in a tab** but not in the window unfortunately.